# Canceling user input of specific characters in an input element using RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I was wondering how to prevent a user from typing in whitespaces into an input element.

This is what I got so far:

```
const userTypedInSearchBox = Observable.fromEvent(searchBar, 'input').asHot();

whenAnyOf(userTypedInSearchBox).subscribe(e => {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lbzlcv)

Here is one way, you could achieve it. I think the issue you are facing is due to the event type you are listening for.

```
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

var searchBar = document.querySelector('input');
const userTypedInSearchBox = fromEvent(searchBar, 'keydown');

userTypedInSearchBox.subscribe((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
      console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```